# How to Getting all custom options of a product in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, custom

```
$productss = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product_id);

$theoptions = $productss->getOptions();

foreach($theoptions as $opkey=> $opval){

echo $opval->getOptionId().'|'.$opval->getTitle().'<br>';

}
```

This Code does not get all options for the product I need all options with 'option_type_id', 'option_id' etc...

[image: I am trying to get all custom options data for product.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try These Code to get the custom option collection

```
<?php
$product_id = 100;
$productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product_id);
foreach ($productCollection->getOptions() as $value) {
echo "<strong>Custom Option:" . $i . "</strong><br/>";
echo "Custom Option TYPE: " . $value->getType() . "<br/>";
echo "Custom Option TITLE: " . $value->getTitle() . "<br/>";
echo "Custom Option Values: <br/>";
// Getting Values if it has option values, case of select,dropdown,radio,multiselect
$values = $value->getValues();
foreach ($values as $values) {
print_r($values->getData());
}
}
?>
```